# Solve system of two trigonometric equations (related to flight mechanics)

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have a constrained gimbal model which uses $\hat\phi$ and $\hat\theta$ to drive a camera. I derived following two equations connecting my gimbal to classical aircraft Euler angles (or Tait-Bryan angles whichever name you prefer) $\phi,\theta,\psi$

$\sin(\theta)=\sin(\hat\theta)*\cos(\hat\phi)$

$\tan(\psi)=\tan(\hat\theta)*\sin(\hat\phi)$

I want now to solve this system for $\hat\phi$ and $\hat\theta$ but my time at university is to long ago ;) Can you give me a hint or the solution? I already tried wolfram alpha but it only offers solutions which probably can be simplified a lot more.

Comment: The first equation becomes $2\sin\hat\theta=\sin(\hat\theta+\hat\phi)$. There is no way to solve for $\hat\phi$ or $\hat\theta$, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the first equation by $\sin(\hat\theta)$ and the second by $\tan(\hat\theta)$, square both of these & use pythagorus, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\hat\theta)} \right)^2 = 1- \left( \frac{\tan(\psi)}{\tan(\hat\theta)} \right)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply by $\sin^2(\hat\theta)$ and use pythagorus
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sin^2(\theta)  = 1-\cos^2(\hat\theta)-  \cos^2(\hat\theta) \tan^2(\psi) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Rearrange a bit
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \cos^2(\hat\theta) = \frac{1-\sin^2(\theta)}{1+\tan^2(\psi)}
\end{eqnarray*}
square root to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \cos(\hat\theta) = \pm \cos(\theta)\cos(\psi).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Hitn.

Calling

$$
u=\sin\hat\theta\\
v=\sin \hat\phi
$$

we have

$$
\sin^2\theta = u^2(1-v^2)\\
\tan^2\psi = \frac{u^2}{1-u^2}v^2
$$

then

$$
1-\frac{\sin^2\theta}{u^2}=\frac{1-u^2}{u^2}\tan^2\psi
$$

so we find

$$
u^2 = \cos^2\psi(\sin^2\theta + \tan^2\psi)
$$

etc.